# Why do data() and c_str() return char const*, while operator[] returns char&?

Tags: c++, string, constants, software-design

Why do `std::string::data` and `std::string::c_str()` return pointers to *const* chars, while `std::string::operator[]` returns references to *mutable* chars?

```
std::string string("eightfold is the greatest");

auto s = string.data();
*s = 'r'; // illegal

auto t = &string[0];
*t = 'r'; // totally fine

auto& c = string[0];
c = 'r'; // totally fine
```

Why don’t `std::string::data()` and `std::string::c_str()` return `char*`, or why doesn’t `std::string::operator[]` return `char const&`?

What is the rationale behind this?

Comment: Note that `&s[0]` returns `char*` which cannot be treated as null-terminated string, while `char const*` returned by `c_str()`  is null-terminated string.

Comment: @Nawaz, I'm almost sure the null is guaranteed to be there in C++11 (along with it being contiguous), even if you can't modify it.

Comment: @Nawaz: In C++11 `&s[0]` is guaranteed to be a C-string. In pre C++11 versions of the language it was not guaranteed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`operator []` gives you direct access to the controlled sequence of `std::string` object. `c_str()` originally did not.

In the original specification of `std::string` the stored sequence was not required to be a zero-terminated string. This meant that in general case `c_str()` could not return a direct pointer to the stored sequence. It had to return a pointer to a completely independent, separately allocated temporary copy of the controlled sequence (with an added zero terminator character). For this reason, trying to modify the C-string returned by `c_str()` made no sense at all. Any modifications applied to that separate C-string would not be propagated to the actual controlled sequence. (In fact, the specification explicitly prohibited any modification attempts. For example, for an empty `std::string` an implementation could simply return a pointer to a string literal `""`, which was of course non-modifiable and could be easily shared between all `std::string` objects.) So, it made perfect sense to make `c_str()` to return `const char *`.

C++11 changed the internal specification of `c_str()` making it to return a direct pointer to the actual controlled sequence. But the external spec of `c_str()` remained unchanged to keep it aligned with the legacy spec.

Comment: No, it didn't have to be "a completely independent, separately allocated temporary copy of the controlled sequence".  Probably a NUL would simply be appended (but not counted in `size()`, you would have (strictly) `size() < capacity()` instead of the usual `size() <= capacity()`

Comment: @Ben Voigt: My "It had..." sentence was intended to continue the previous one: "In general case...". Yes, it is a well-known fact that real-life implementations preferred to store the zero-terminator explicitly and implement lightweight `c_str()`. However, in general case an "abstract" implementation would allocate an independent buffer. The entire original spec of `c_str()` is deliberately written to support this approach. I.e. regardless of what `c_str()` actually returned, an abstract program had to assume that the buffer was independently allocated.

Answer (score 3):

For historical reasons, C++ and its standard library support C-strings (character arrays), and lots of C++ code uses C-strings for input and output.

You can also imagine a possible implementation of the std::string that keeps its data in a character array.  This would normally be a completely private implementation detail, that is not exposed through the class' public interface.

EDIT: to be explicit, a class would normally not expose non-const views of its private data.  To see why this would be an issue, imagine the following code:

```
std::string s("abc");  
char* ps = s.c_str();  //  ps[0] == 'a' and ps[3] == '\0'
ps[3] = 'd';  // string is not null terminated
printf("%s", s.c_str());  // printing non-terminated string.
```

Such a change would allow a user of the class to change its private data in a way that breaks invariants, namely the following invariant: "The character buffer used for storage will be null-terminated."

Part of the contract of `operator[]` is that the caller must not provide an argument greater or equal to the length of the string.  The [`at(size_t pos)` member function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at) enforces bounds checking by throwing an exception.  The `std::string::operator[]` can still be used unsafely, *but* it's possible to at least [*document* a contract](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at), unlike with a pointer dereference operator as in `ps[3]`.

END OF EDIT

But in order to support interoperability with functions that expect a `const char*` C-string, `std::string` exposes this character buffer.

Of course, like with `std::vector`, users might want to modify individual elements (characters) in a string, which is why the string provides `operator[]`.

(In reality, `string` implementations often have a character buffer of fixed length that they keep internally, and then "reallocate" on the heap if the string's contents exceed that fixed length. This is called the "small string optimization.")

Why is there a `data()` member function, you may ask, when there is a perfectly serviceable `c_str()` member function?  I think this is there to simplify generic programming:  `std::array` and `std::vector` also have `data()` member functions, and `std::string`s are designed to act like containers.

Comment: “But in order to support interoperability with functions that expect a `const char*` C-string, `std::string` exposes this character buffer.” Isn’t `char*` implicitly convertible to `char const*`?

Comment: This answer completely misses the question. It's not about why there *is* a `c_str()` function, but why it returns a `char const*` and not `char*`.