# copying a fixed length of data from an std::istream to a string

Tags: c++, iostream

I'd like to copy a fixed length of data from an std::istream to a string:

```
std::istream & operator >> ( std::istream & is, LogMsg & msg )
{
    // read in 4 bytes - a uint32_t that describes the number of bytes in message:
    // next, read the message bytes into the LogMsg

    typedef std::istream_iterator<unsigned char> Iter;

    Iter            i (is);
    uint32_t        nSize   = 0;
    std::string &   sMsg    = msg.MsgRef();

    is >> nSize;
    sMsg.reserve(nSize);

    std::copy(
        i.begin(), i.begin() + nSize,
        std::back_inserter(sMsg)
    );

    return is;
}
```

I can't use this solution, as the std::istream_iterator::begin() function on the iterator is c++11 only (I'm constrained to -std=gnu++0x with gcc 4.4.7

So, how can I copy a fixed length of data from an input stream into a string?

I originally loooked at std::istream::read, which seems to fit - it has the following syntax

```
is.read (buffer,length);
```

But I don't think you can read into the internal buffers of a string and I'd like to avoid a copy to a temporary buffer.  Can I use a streambuf somehow?

Comment: AFAIK there is no `begin()`/`end()` functions for `istream_iterator` in C++11.

Comment: Streams are _flows of data_, not containers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The obvious solution is `std::copy_n`:

```
std::copy_n( std::istreambuf_iterator<char>( is ), size, std::back_inserter( msg ) );
```

This will only work if you can be sure that the characters are there,
however.  If you encounter end of file while trying to read the
characters, undefined behavior ensues.  Which means that although it is
an obvious solution, it maybe isn't a good one.

However, in C++11, officially, and in earlier implementations, in
practice, you can read into the internal buffer.  You must make sure
that the string has enough space:

```
msg.resize( size );
is.read( &msg[0], msg.size() );
```

(For some reason, there isn't a non-const version of
`std::string::data()`, despite the guarantee of underlying contiguity in
C++11.)

Answer (score 3):

You can copy into a string's internal buffer, just make sure it's the right size:

```
sMsg.resize(nSize);
is.read(&sMsg[0], nSize);
```

It's less efficient than the solution with `begin()` since you have to zero-initialize a whole bunch of data that you're immediately overwriting. But it will work pre-C++11.

Comment: Technically this is UB pre-C++11.

Comment: Contiguity not strictly guaranteed. Though in practice it _sort of_ was. Actually as of GCC 4.9 I think they're still using the old implementation with COW, which is non-compliant in C++11. Moral of the story, be very careful with direct string access.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit But in practice, it will work.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Contiguity was not guaranteed intentionally, in order to allow implementations along the lines of `rope`.  In practice, no one ever used them, so they added the contiguity guarantee.  And the g++ implementation of `std::string` has always been contiguous; the above will work with it.

Comment: @James: [I don't believe that's true](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21431742/560648); JW says [strings are still COW in GCC 4.9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21431633/does-g-meets-stdstring-c11-requirements#comment32348898_21431742) and doesn't that kill the contiguity guarantee? Wait, does it? Hm. Yeah, [never mind I guess not](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1986974/560648).

Comment: @James: As for it being "intentional", that was called into question in C++98 the first time somebody noticed that `std::string::data()` and `std::string::c_str()` have constant time complexity. The fact that the change made was to enforce contiguity rather than give `std::string::c_str()` non-constant complexity says quite a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Use `std::copy_n()`:

```
std::copy_n(i, nSize, std::back_inserter(sMsg));
```

Comment: This will result in undefined behavior (and not an error!) if you encounter end of file before reading the `n` characters.

Comment: @JamesKanze Why is that so?

Comment: Because the standard says so.  Why it says so, I don't know; I suspect it's just a case of the authors not wanting to specify anything in particular.