# How to read a string from a binary file?

Tags: c++, string, binary

I am trying to read a string(`ver`) from a binary file. the number of characters(`numc`) in the string is also read from the file.This is how I read the file:

```
 uint32_t numc;
 inFile.read((char*)&numc, sizeof(numc));
 char* ver = new char[numc];
 inFile.read(ver, numc);
 cout << "the version is: " << ver << endl;
```

what I get is the string that I expect plus some other symbols. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: it is not null terminated in the file. You will need to store it in a length-aware string storage, like for example std::string, or provide the null character yourself. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27061489/copying-a-fixed-length-of-data-from-an-stdistream-to-a-string

Comment: Thanks for the response @Kenny Ostrom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `char*` string is a *nul terminated* sequence of characters. Your code ignores the nul termination part. Here's how it should look

```
uint32_t numc;
inFile.read((char*)&numc, sizeof(numc));
char* ver = new char[numc + 1]; // allocate one extra character for the nul terminator
inFile.read(ver, numc);
ver[numc] = '\0'; // add the nul terminator
cout << "the version is: " << ver << endl;
```

Also `sizeof(numc)` not `size(numc)` although maybe that's a typo.

Comment: If this doesn't work for you, make sure the [endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of `numc` matches the endian of the file

Comment: You were right. I'd forgotten the null character. the problem is solved. Thanks.

Comment: Don't forget to `delete[] ver` when you are done using it. Better to use `std::string` instead, or at least `std::unique_ptr<char[]>`

Comment: @RemyLebeau I don't understand why is that a problem?

Comment: @MahshadJavidan Memory leak vs no memory leak. You have to `delete` whatever you allocate with `new`. `std::unique_ptr` will handle that for you. And you don't have to worry about that at all with `std::string`.

Comment: @john alternatively, instead of null-terminating the string, you can use `cout.write(ver, numc)` instead of `cout << ver`.